# Show/hide div based on dropdown box selection -

Tags: laravel

I am stuck at show/hide div based on dropdown box selection. In the code, alert message is showing as per selection, but  is not hiding.

Dropdown menu

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="animalstatus">Animal Status: </label>
    <select class="form-control animalsold" name="animalstatus" id="animalstatus">
       <option value="Available">Available</option>
       <option value="Sold">Sold</option>
       <option value="Died">Died</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Card which need to show when selection done

```
<div class="card card-default border border-success bg-white" id="#showsolddetails" 
     style="display:none">
  <div class="card-header">
     <h3 class="card-title">Animal Sold Information</h3>
        ----- Some Textbox here
</div>
```

Script

```
                $(function () {

                    $('#animalstatus').on('change', function() {
                        
                            if ( this.value == 'Died')
                                {
                                    $("#showsolddetails").show();
                                    alert("Died");
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    //$("#showsolddetails").hide();
                                    alert("Not Died");
                                }
                            

                        });
                    });
```

Did i miss something..... Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's just a typo. Remove `#` from `id="#showsolddetails"`.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` in the div shouldn't be prefixed with `#`. `#` is only used for selection.

```
<div class="card card-default border border-success bg-white" id="showsolddetails">
```